# In a multi-project SBT build, how can I run 1 main program?

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-project build.  One of my source directories is called "core" that unpacks down to the source files in normal project structure (main/scala/...)

Using the sbt command line, how can I run a main program called Hello.scala (object extends App)?

Tried:

```
> run my.package.path.Hello
> run Hello
> run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run some task scoped only to one subproject ("module"), you can do it with the `project/task` syntax, e.g.

```
core/run
```

See documentation on [Scopes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scopes.html).